# How to use egrep to find a repeated cluster of characters (e.g. abc-abc-abc)?

Tags: unix, grep

I'm learning how to use egrep command, i want to find some words has repeat **3 chars** in one line (e.g., `abc-abc-abc`; `ssd-ssd-ssd`).

I tried some commands like

```
egrep '[a-z][a-z][a-z]{3}' file 
grep -e'{([a-z][a-z][a-z]){3}}' file
```

but does not work. it just print all word has 9 chars

Answer (score 3):

You can use

`grep -e '\(\<[[:alnum:]]\{3\}\>\).*\<\1\>.*\<\1\>'`

`\<[[:alnum:]]\{3\}\>` matches a word formed by exactly 3 alphanumeric chars. `\<\>` insures surrounding chars are not alphanumeric.

`\(...\)` puts the match in var \1 to be recalled later

`\<\1\>` matches a word whose value is exactly the same as the remembered match.

Comment: To generalize it more along the lines you suggest, with a couple of optimizations, I'd use `egrep` `'([[:alnum:]]{3})([^[:alnum:]]\1){2}'` to avoid the syntactical clutter that makes it hard to read. Your use of `\< \>` requires whitespace or a punctuation delimiter between items. I did the same thing differently. Also suggest using two repeat counts (in case there are many more than 3 in a row needed, to avoid writing a long regex).

Answer (score 2):

**Answer** (*complicated example using capture groups and repeat counts*):

```
egrep '([a-z]{3})(-\1){2}'
```

That matches following pattern, with hyphen as only allowed delimiter.

```
abc-abc-abc
ssd-ssd-ssd
zab-zab-zab 
.
.
.
```

The above example has two sets of parens (capture groups); each captures its matched text into its its capture-group respective buffer. We only need to parenthesize the second match expression so we can give it a repeat count, and interested in the captured text of the 2nd group.

**Easier Example**

This is a similar case but easier to understand. It matches 3 identical lowercase letters in a row:

```
egrep '([a-z])\1\1'
```

The `([a-z])` is a capture group that matches one lowercase letter and stores the matched character in a capture group buffer. Note: Each `\1` matches the *captured* text (in this case 1 matched character) again.

`NOTE`: The capture group matches the *first* character of the sequence, so two additional matches against saved text from the first match are required in order to match three identical characters in a row.  The following example is identical to the one above, except it uses a repeat count `(2)` to repeat the 2nd term two times.

```
egrep '([a-z])\1{2}'
```

I tested it this way:

---

```
$ echo "aaa" | egrep '([a-z])\1{2}'
aaa
$ echo "zzz" | egrep '([a-z])\1{2}'
zzz
$ echo "zaz" | egrep '([a-z])\1{2}'
```

---

<sup>*note: no output for third echo line*</sup>

**How Capture Groups Work**

Unescaped parenthesis are use group expression elements together for repeating as a group or providing an operation on them, but *also* cause the matched text to be captured into an internal buffer.

The first capture group, from left to right in the regex, is `\1`,  second is `\2`, third `\3` ...

Anywhere you want to substitute the captured match text into your regex, use the backslash'd number corresponding to the capture group of interest.